# Rails migrations with the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

How do people cope with this problem elegantly?

I had a migration that created a table, then another to remove that table, now I want to re-introduce it, problem is i cant as they have the same name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, Rails complains only about migration name *only*. Well, migration name has no affect on its functionality, so you can just use a different one.

Comment: You do understand be correctly, and this is what I have done. However, I believe I follow best practice, and name my migrations inline with their functionality, therefore naming two identical migrations with different names is not very elegant.

Comment: @Jon I'm normally quite picky about code style, but you surpass even me :) There's nothing wrong with "create table again" or "create table, attempt #2".

Comment: ha! fair point I suppose, i'll try and keep the OCD in check.