# ActiveRecord migration not executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I am new to rails, and created a custom migration to change my database structure using Rails Generate. Here is the command I issued: rails g migration users.

Now, in the file it created, I inputed:

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :first_name
    add_column :last_name
    remove_column :name
  end
end
```

When I run rake db:migrate nothing happens. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: If you created the file entirely on your own then I would guess that you omitted the timestamp at the beginning of the filename.  Rails records which migrations have been executed in a table (schema_migrations) in your database and uses that timestamp to identify them.  Without that timestamp db:migrate will just skip the migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not running at all? It's hard to say based on the info you gave. Perhaps you should try a migration with a more unique name? Something like:

```
rails g migration ConvertUsersNamesToSingleField
```

I'm not sure if it's cool to have two migrations with the same name.  But with short generic names like `Users` that might be the problem here.  And it usually can't hurt to have a verbose and descriptive migration name, for posterity and clarity.

This questions agree that migration with non unique names don't work: [Rails migrations with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528577/rails-migrations-with-the-same-name)

---

But even when ran, this will raise errors.  You need to include table names in those column calls, and you need to specify a type when creating fields.

```
class ConvertUsersNamesToSingleField < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
    remove_column :users, :name
  end
end
```