# How to redo a migration in Rails 5 when there is a foreign key involved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a few connected problems here. So I have begun to add topic back into my app. However when I try to create a new post, I get "Topic must exist". I am not sure what is missing for this to go through specifically.

I do know that I need to somehow redo

AddTopicReferenceToBlogs migration because right now my blogs table looks like this:

```
create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_blogs_on_slug", unique: true
  end
```

The t.integer "topic_id" is missing.

I know I cannot rerun AddTopicReferenceToBlogs because I will get an identical.

If I try to do a rake db:migrate:down VERSION=

I get this error:

```
== 20170725215733 AddTopicReferenceToBlogs: reverting =========================
-- remove_reference(:blogs, :topic, {:foreign_key=>true})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
Table 'blogs' has no foreign key for {:to_table=>"topics", :column=>"topic_id"}
```

By the way my Topic.rb file looks like this:

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
 validates_presence_of :title
end
```

Comment: Can you post the content of this migration `AddTopicReferenceToBlogs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no quick answer to your problem, but I think what will help you is to understand that you CAN redo AddTopicReferenceToBlogs, you are just going to have to give it a different name.

This documentation speaks to that:
[Rails migrations with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528577/rails-migrations-with-the-same-name)

Try something like:

```
rails g migration add_reference_of_topic_to_blogs topic:references
```

That should work assuming that you haven't screwed up some other migrations in the process as well. Rails migrations can get pretty hairy if you are not sure of what you are doing.

Comment: thank you, I did have some other migrations that were getting in the way, but once I resolved those, this answer did work. I still have some other issues related to this but I will ask those questions on another topic if need be. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You may still have a problem if this doesn't execute correctly in your dev environment.

```
rails db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

If you just added a new migration to fix the old one, this full database reset may fail because you now have duplicate migrations trying to `add_reference :blogs, :topic, ...`. This will be a problem for your teammates and when you deploy to production.

Assumptions:

1. You generated an empty migration named `AddTopicReferenceToBlogs` and ran it with `rails db:migrate` (or `rake db:migrate`).
2. When you checked your `schema.rb` afterwards, the foreign key you expected to be there (`topic_id`), wasn't.
3. You edited the empty migration to add a line that used `add_reference` and ran `rails db:migrate` again.
4. The schema still didn't contain `blogs.topic_id`.
5. You tried to rollback the migration with `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=???` and it failed (... because you were trying to rollback a migration that never actually ran. Rails can't remove a reference it never added to begin with).

Answer:

1. Don't add a duplicate migration that does the same thing, but with a different class name.
2. Comment out the `add_reference` line in the bad migration `AddTopicReferenceToBlogs`.
3. Rollback the empty migration (undo the bad thing you did).
4. Reactivate the `add_reference` line.
5. `rake db:migrate` again, this time correctly adding the foreign key you expected to `schema.rb`.

In the future, use this command to generate a pre-filled-in migration for these types of associations.

```
rails g migration AddTopicToBlog topic:belongs_to
```

Alternatives:

```
rails g migration AddTopicToBlogs topic:belongs_to
rails g migration AddTopicToBlog topic:references
rails g migration AddYouCanSayWhateverYouWantHereToBlog topic:references
```